# In Excel, how do I reference a local worksheet within a template?

Tags: excel, templates, reference

I am creating my own template which I need to use data from a worksheet called Schedules. The template contains 3 sheets, **none of which** are the Schedules sheet. This template will only be used in workbooks where the Schedules sheet **already exists**.

My question is, how do I reference a local worksheet which isn't in the template?

Whenever I create the template I reference the Schedules sheet but it asks for a file destination. How can I force it to look for a local sheet, even though the sheet won't exist until the template is actually used?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how complex your formulas, this could get messy pretty quickly, but one option would be to use the `INDIRECT` formula.

Some examples are below:

- Gives you the value of A1 on the Schedules sheet
  `=INDIRECT("Schedules!"&"A1")`
- Looks up the ID '5' in the range A1:C20 in the Schedules sheet and returns the corresponding value in column B
  `=VLOOKUP(5,INDIRECT("Schedules!"&"A1:C20"),2,0)`
- Multiplies two values on the Schedules sheet
  `=INDIRECT("Schedules!"&"A1")*INDIRECT("Schedules!"&"A2")`

Once you get your formulas working you can move your templates to the workbook that has the Schedules. All of your formulas will update with appropriate values, and for the record, calculations should be set to automatic.

Comment: So I already know my formulas work. The issue I'm having is that they do not auto-update. When I include a reference to a worksheet not in the template, it asks which file to look in. I don't get a '#REF' error and so it doesn't auto-update the formula.

Comment: If you follow the approach that I use, the formulas will auto-update

Comment: They don't update automatically. In order for them to realise that a change has been made, each cell must be edited (F2) and then entered. Not even using the calculate sheet function will work and often times the #REF err is within the formula and therefore it no longer looks for a Schedules sheet

Comment: Ok then. I always test my answers before I post them, and I have added and removed a sample "Schedules" sheet several times and can watch the cells go from #REF to populated values and back without having to recalculate or hit F2. I've provided a sample document [here](http://www.filedropper.com/indirectformula-samplefile). Maybe I'm interpreting your issue incorrectly

Comment: So this works, but only once I enter the cell (as I mentioned previously) and also is not what I was looking for.
I have already a template complete with formula referencing Schedules. I want to be able to _insert **my** template_ into any workbook with a worksheet called Schedules. The formula in the template (which has been added to the workbook) should then update automatically. They don't. The formula continue to point at a non-existant workbook.

Comment: You'll need to then update the formulas to include the word Schedules in it. See the updated code